# Is DRM+ti,lcdc driver capable of showing tux logo when kernel is booting?

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, display

I would like to show a tux logo on am335x processor using a fbcon + framebuffer driver. At the moment i have ti-linux 3.14 configured to use DRM and ti,lcdc driver. Also i have devicetree lcd panel node written with usage of tilcdc driver. **Is possible to display logo using only ti,lcdc driver or should i use da8xx-fb driver? Or mix usage of these drivers or something?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here and found some information how to do it other way thanks to psplash https://e2e.ti.com/support/arm/sitara_arm/f/791/t/398816. But this is  not solution for my question. It's only a workaround in userspace. I would like to have kernel solution.